# Coordinator Layout and FAB. Wrong behaviour issue

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

Have regular layout markup(bottom sheet style) with Coordinator Layout as root view & Fab with NestedScroll view layout as anchor. 
AndroidStudio show preview as i suppose to must be. Fab placed between appbar and nested view. 
When i'm run my app get next: 
[image]

It's not that i wanna get. So, after some time spending (receive response for network request) my Fab get place where it must be. I tried to check what wrong, and find "trigger" which move button to needed place. It was textView.setText("some text") for TextView which placed on app bar container.

I also try another experiment, call Switch state change, change my custom view in runtime etc...all this element also placed on app bar near my TextView. I make a decision that only TextView changes trigger my Fab for place changing. 
So, i try next: in my fragment onCreateView method, i get root view and call `view.requestLayout();`
not good decision, because view not measured already, and i move this call to onResume. Still nothing. So i wrap this calling to Handler with delay and my button draw in needed place. 
[image]

So, i try to change time of delay up to 0ms, and its work fine(ok, handler start another thread, and thats why even 0ms produce some delay which gave ability request layout after measurement operation). But main issue for me is hand calling layout request in runtime in my case when it must work fine from scratch.

Did anyone have same problem and find some other solution without hand calling?